# Magento 2, how to get list of product by item_id?

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, quoteitem

Using `Magento 2.2`, `REST API`. What `URI` of api for get list of product by `item_id`?

> This below get all item without **defined item_id**

```
GET /index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine/items HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

[
    {
        "item_id": 2094,
        "sku": "Food with option 6-AS-----",
        "qty": 2,
        "name": "Food with option 6",
        "price": 0,
        "product_type": "configurable",
        "quote_id": "1173",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "2",
                        "option_value": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "3",
                        "option_value": "7,9"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": "4",
                        "option_value": "10,11,12"
                    }
                ],
                "configurable_item_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "155",
                        "option_value": 57
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**--- ANSWER ---**

I use `quote_id` instead of `item_id` then use `URI`

> GET {{url}}/index.php/rest/V1/carts/{{quote_id}}/items

Comment: This will get respond the same `json` above.

Answer (score 1):

**catalogProductRepositoryV1**

```
Implementation Notes : Get product list
```

> Method : GET

```
<magento.host>/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2905
```

**Parameters for Item id**

```
searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][field] => entity_id

searchCriteria[filterGroups][][filters][][value] => Value
```

> Note : Please pass authentication Bearer of Admin token or Change the
>   resource to `SELF`

Comment: The `entity_id` product not for `item_id`.

Comment: `item_id` in this case use for `product` that selected its option for use in cart. i think `item_id` not stand for raw `product`.

Comment: Do you need `quote_item` ?

Comment: Do you mean that `item_id` is the id of `quote_item`?

Comment: What is your exact need ? where do you wanna call the API ?

Comment: I to use `item_id` to find list of bought product.

Comment: `<magento.host>/rest/V1/orders/items/1`

Comment: Not work for this `{{url}}/V1/orders/items/2094`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80365/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-bong-channarith).